# Invoking a click on a specific div

Tags: html, vb.net, webbrowser-control

I'm trying to invoke a click using my vb.net app on this div

```
<div class="name"><a href="www.website.com">Name of said Item</a></div>
```

So I'm using WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("name").InvokeMember("click")

However whenever I do this I get an error of

"An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in TractorPartComparison.exe

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

The code that I'm using currently works for another site but for some reason for that specific tag it crashes my app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**.GetElementById("name")** looks for **`<div id="name">`** not **`<div class="name">`**

Comment: Well that teaches me for reusing code. How would I go around fixing this however? Changing it to GetElementByClass does not work and I can't find any fix currently.

Comment: getElementsByClassName return an array of elements so you need to pick the one you need.

Comment: getElementsByClassName' is not a member of System.Windows.Forms.HtmlDocument

Would HtmlDocument.GetElementsByTagName be better suited?

Comment: Sorry mixed Javascript with VB ^^ Like you said use GetElementsByTagName and loop through the elements and check for the class attribute

Comment: I'm trying to use a loop and I'm getting no crashing however no results either.

Dim theElementCollection As HtmlElementCollection
        theElementCollection = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("name")
        For Each curElement As HtmlElement In theElementCollection
            Dim controlName As String = curElement.GetAttribute("name").ToString
            curElement.InvokeMember("click")
        Next

In my case there should only be one div class name.

Comment: TagName is DIV not name

Comment: It just freezes now sadly. Possibly stuck in a loop?

Comment: Could you tell me how to initiate a click on the div via Javascript at all please?